# stable package is different to rmadison query

Tags: apt, devuan

I'm having difficulties with the gpodder application and I'm trying to figure out what's causing the issue. I have installed the package from stable, testing, and backports repositories, and I have also asked for help via IRC.

None of these attempts have resolved my problem so far. I'm wondering if there might be some underlying issue causing the trouble.

When I simulate to install godder from the stable repository (my default repo), apt says it would install Version 3.10.17-1 from stable. So far, so good.

Pulling the available versions via rmadison, it shows a different version for the stable repo.

In my sources lists (stable.list) I used the distributions codename, where ***chimaera*** is the current stable.
There's also a devuan.list in the folder which refers to an older codename, but this one is commented out.

```
***devuan.list***
# autogenerated by devuan-baseconf
# decomment following lines to  enable the developers devuan repository
#deb http://packages.devuan.org/devuan beowulf main
#deb-src http://packages.devuan.org/devuan beowulf main
```

```
***stable.list***
## package repositories
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-backports main contrib non-free
```

So, what could be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the `devscripts` package information in Devuan](https://pkginfo.devuan.org/cgi-bin/package-query.html?c=package&q=devscripts=2.21.3%20deb11u1), I get the impression that it is copied as-is from Debian with no change, so

```
rmadison gpodder
```

queries the Debian servers, not Devuan’s. As a result, you get information about `gpodder` in Debian, where “stable” is now Debian 12.

Devuan Chimaera is based on Debian 11, so Devuan “stable” is now based on Debian “oldstable”, with `gpodder` 3.10.17-1.

Instead of relying on `rmadison`, you might want to use `apt policy` — that will show packages that are available in your configured repositories. Alternatively, if Devuan has an appropriate metadata service (Madison), you can tell `rmadison` to use that with the `-u` option; I don’t know whether such a service is available, let alone its URL.

Comment: I used to have the testing branch in my repos, but I think that rmadison (or is there another tool?) is the right coice to see all the versions of all branches. Otherwise I would have to put all available repos into my sources list. But I appreciate your answer and I asked in the devuan forum if there is an appropriate metadata service. I will come back with an answer here.

Comment: Yes, `rmadison` is indeed very useful, but only if you use a metadata service that matches your distribution.